# jenkins matrix artifacts with PostBuildScript

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to use the [PostBuildScript](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin) plugin to deploy the artifacts from a Matrix job that runs on several slaves.

The slaves are archiving the artifacts-- but its unclear how to access them from the PostBuildScript.  How can I get the matrix node artifacts into the master workspace where the PostBuildScript job is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called Copy To Slave Plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin

This can copy artifacts from master to slave or vice versa. Inorder to get your work done you can use this plugin. It has a feature called "Copy files back to master node". This will copy the files back to the masters workspace. So you don't need post build script plugin to copy artifacts. This way will be more simpler.

Comment: This is a great idea.  Alas, it doesn't seem to work properly: [JENKINS-25346](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25346)

Comment: Looks like they fixed it in [1.4.4](https://github.com/jenkinsci/copy-to-slave-plugin/compare/copy-to-slave-1.4.3...copy-to-slave-1.4.4)